# Excute bash script "ps aux | wc -l" in java response empty result

Tags: java, ubuntu, runtime, processbuilder

I used java to execute bash script to count total of the process. But, the result I got is empty in input BufferedReader.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps aux | wc -l");
                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.error(TAG, ex);
            }
```

but when I execute "ps aux | wc -l" in terminal it return "250".
Can anyone help me.
Thanks so much.

Comment: I scanned the web for a while. It seems that the processing above is somehow deprecated. You're supposed to use a ProcessBuilder instead.

Comment: Thanks, I work with ProcessBuilder but I can't work with this situation. regard